# Pass "element" object to a class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, constructor, typeerror

I have two classes in separate modules "project" and "gallery". One class is for an object that stores data about a single project and another is for an object that stores all projects.

I'm trying to pass "element" object to "gallery" object, save it in constructor and then use in on of methods to pass to "project" object.

EDIT 2:
My code is:

gallery.js:

```
import {project} from './project.js';


class gallery
{
constructor(selector)
{      
    this.projects = [];
    let parent = document.createElement("div");
    Object.assign(this, parent);
    this.parent = selector;

}

AddProject(name, imgsrc, desc, tags)
{
    const temp = new project(name,imgsrc,desc,tags);
    this.projects.push(temp);
}

PrintCallback(currentValue, index, arr)
{
    currentValue.PrintImage(this.parent);
}

PrintGallery()
{
    this.projects.forEach(this.PrintCallback);
}
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

let gallerySelector = document.querySelector("#portfolio-gallery");

const grafika = new gallery(gallerySelector);

grafika.AddProject("aaa","logo.png","qwerty",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","baner.png","aaa",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","kolo.png","aaa",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","plakietka.png","aaa",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","stark.png","aaa",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","targaryen.png","aaa",['aaa']);
grafika.AddProject("aaa","plakat.png","aaa",['aaa']);

grafika.PrintGallery();

});
```

project.js:

```
export class project
{
constructor(name,img,desc,tags)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imgsrc = img;
    this.tags = tags;
}

CreateDiv(code,cssClass)
{
    const template = document.createElement("div");
    template.innerHTML = code;
    template.classList.add(cssClass);
    return template;
}

PrintDesc(selector)
{       
    let parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent = selector;

    const content = 
'<h1>'+this.name+'</h1>'+'<p>'+this.desc+'</p>'+'<h4>'+this.tags.join(", 
")+'</h4>'
    const content_div = this.CreateDiv(content,"project-content");

    parent.appendChild(content_div);

}

PrintImage(selector)
{    
    let parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent = selector;

    const img = '<img  src="grafika/'+this.imgsrc+'">';
    const img_div = this.CreateDiv(img,"project-img");
    img_div.classList.add("tile");

    parent.appendChild(img_div);

    $(parent).hide();
    $(parent).fadeIn(500);
}
};
```

Comment: How is method (class?) `PrintImage()` defined? BTW it's a common practice to have the first letter of a class name uppercase only.

Comment: `PrintImage()` is method of class "project". I edited the post so now you can check this.

Comment: The 3rd example block is class gallery but it's calling method `PrintImage()`...shouldn't it be class project instead? Otherwise how does class gallery inherit `PrintImage()`? I see no `extend`  or `super`...

Comment: Class "gallery" has array of "project" objects - `this.projects = []; I fill this array with objects in a different method. So `currentValue` is an element of that array. I will also mention that method `PrintCallback` is called by forEach() function.

Comment: It kinda looks as if you are trying to develop a [function factory](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e)

Comment: All of the code works great when i change parameter of `PrintImage()` to this `currentValue.PrintImage(document.querySelector("#portfolio-gallery"));` so this must be something wrong with "parent" variable or I don't know

Comment: Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913723/2813224). The demo is a class capable of binding Event Listeners passing any selector, multiple events and callbacks. Vote it if it's useful.

Comment: yeah, it helped me, thanks. The `Object.assign();` is what i needed. Voted but i have less than 15 reputations.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that, anyways yeah `Object.assign()` is the heart of most function factories.

Comment: Nope. This still not working. I thought it was ok becouse I forgot to change this line: `currentValue.PrintImage(document.querySelector("#portfolio-gallery"));` passing this.parent to function doesn't work. Nothing works. I can't find an answer on the net. I try everything. God...

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to understand your code but it's incomplete and class functions are tightly integrated to the point that any association, scope, and reference that's a little off can easily break everything in a domino effect.

Comment: I've put all the js code now. EDIT: After many experiments with the code I finally found a problem - I can't use class variables inside the callback function. I moved the parameter passing to the constructor so there's no need to use any variables in callback function and it works. But why does it work like that?

Comment: What is currentValue? The constructor properties are accessible by the keyword `this` which points to constructor. Only methods of class has access to `this`, these methods can be inherited by another class using super. All of this and much more is designed to isolate class props and methods, etc.-- modularization.

Comment: currentValue is param of `forEach()` callback function, it's the value of the current array element. I use `forEach()` to lunch `PrintImage()` for every objects inside the `this.projects` array. It's strange but I can use variables in every function except callback one despite the fact that method is in the class declaration.

Comment: I figured it out! The callback function had `this` value set to 'undefined' becouse of non-use of the proper parameter. I added the last parameter: `this.projects.forEach(this.PrintProjects,this);` and now i can use variables in that function. Everything is clear now. Thanks a lot for your help i can move on with my project now, finally.

Comment: That's great! `this` is a very critical aspect of JS OOP.  Happy coding.